# ruby_dep is preventing me from creating new rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This morning I was creating a new rails app. I decided to start over so I deleted what I'd done previously. When I tried running `rails new appname` I got:

```
Installing ruby_dep 1.5.0
Gem::InstallError: ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.
```

...

```
    An error occurred while installing ruby_dep (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install ruby_dep -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'capybara (~> 2.13)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
192-168-1-4:website Rhys$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile
```

I don't know why I've started getting this error only a few minutes after successfully initialising other rails apps.

I'm on OS X.

Comment: Are you using RVM?  Also, in the directory where you run `rails new appname`, what do you see when you run `ruby -v`/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try  following the instruction and installing `gem install ruby_dep -v '1.5.0'`?

to run bundle install you need to be in the **root directory**, if you are in some other folder, you will not be able to run the command.

if you go to the [**ruby_dep github page**](https://github.com/e2/ruby_dep) you will understand the reason of the problem. It probably connected with your ruby version

I quote ruby_dep:

> Automatically helps determine supported Rubies based on .travis.yml file

then also very useful

> **IMPORTANT!! : HOW TO CORRECTLY SOLVE ISSUES**
>
> If you're here because you're having issues, try the following:
>
> **1. Upgrade Ruby.**
>
> Ideally to the latest stable possible. It may be a little (or very!) inconvenient, but it helps everyone in the long run.
>
> Show the awesome Ruby Core Team your support for their work by letting them focus on newer and better Rubies.
>
> **2. Upgrade Ruby anyway.**
>
> If you can't upgrade Ruby because of the environment, work out how to do so anyway.
>
> E.g. if you can't install Ruby 2.2.5 on OSX due to RVM issues (even though Ruby 2.2.5 has been released over 5 months ago), then obviously the RVM project may need help or support of some kind. Help the RVM maintainers out - they're awesome! Or, fork the project and heroically take things into your own hands.
>
> If Apple (or Amazon or whatever hosting service or company) doesn't provide the latest recommended, supported version of Ruby, use Homebrew (or build from sources) or complain to those companies to provide support. It's unfair for them to prevent users from getting better/faster Rubies.
>
> **3. Upgrade Bundler (but even the most recent Bundler may not be enough!)**
>
> Upgrade to a Bundler version that can automatically downgrade the gems for you. If that doesn't help, try this workaround: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Ruby-version-requirements
>
> Work on this "downgrading" feature in Bundler is ongoing, so the best version of Bundler for the job may still be an unreleased version (beta, release candidate, etc.).
>
> Help the Bundler team out if you can - they're awesome!
>
> **4. If all else fails, learn SemVer and USE IT!**
>
> Often, there are older versions of gems that support the Ruby version you need. See http://semver.org/ on how to set version constraints. Then, check out the release notes of the gems you need to know what you're getting (or missing out on).
>
> E.g. You can downgrade to RubyDep 1.3.1 (gem 'ruby_dep', '~> 1.3.1') which allows using Ruby 2.2.4 E.g. Or, You can use Listen 3.0.x (gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.8') to avoid dealing with RubyDep and Listen.
>
> If those gem versions are lacking for any reason (e.g. bugs in Listen 3.0.x fixed in 3.1.x), then e.g. open a request for backporting changes to the 3.0.x branch.
>
> The idea: if you don't need the latest Ruby ... then you probably don't need the latest of every gem either.
>
> **5. If all that isn't possible or it doesn't work ...**
>
> Let me know about it (open an issue), because I'm likely confused about how all the above steps failed.
>
> Or it's a bug I don't know about. Please report it - just in case...

I am just [quoting their github page](https://github.com/e2/ruby_dep)